# Data gets duplicated when written to file

Tags: java, jaxb, bufferedwriter

Im having troubles using either JAXB or BufferedWriter. when i add the employees to the employees list then Marshall the list, i get the list of the employees written to the xml file but it writes the list twice. here is my code.

**Main Class**

```
package schleusner.cameron;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JAXBException         {

        Employees employees = new Employees();
        employees.setEmployees(new ArrayList<Employee>());

        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        e1.setName("codippa");
        e1.setLogin("4:30Pm");


        Employee e2 = new Employee();
        e2.setName("emp1");
        e2.setLogin("5:00PM");


        Employee e3 = new Employee();
        e3.setName("emp2");
        e3.setLogin("8:00AM");


        Employee e4 = new Employee();
        e4.setName("emp3");
        e4.setLogin("1:20AM");


        employees.getEmployees().add(e1);
        employees.getEmployees().add(e2);
        employees.getEmployees().add(e3);
        employees.getEmployees().add(e4);

        BufferedWriter writer1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Cameron\\Desktop\\xmltest\\Employees.xml"));
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employees.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();

        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

        m.marshal(employees, writer1);
        writer1.close();
    }
}
```

**Employees class**

```
package schleusner.cameron;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Employees")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employees {
  private List<Employee> employee;

  @XmlElement(name="Employee")
  public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
      return employee;
  }

  public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employeeList) {
      this.employee = employeeList;
  }
}
```

**Employee Class**

```
package schleusner.cameron;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String login;
    private String logout;
    private String lunchin;
    private String lunchout;

    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getLogout() {
        return logout;
    }

    public void setLogout(String logout) {
        this.logout = logout;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getLunchin() {
        return lunchin;
    }

    public void setLunchin(String lunchin) {
        this.lunchin = lunchin;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getLunchout() {
        return lunchout;
    }

    public void setLunchout(String lunchout) {
        this.lunchout = lunchout;
    }
}
```

**File OutPut**:
https://pastebin.com/raw/aTqmqwHh

Comment: Why don't you try printing the employees array before writing it to the file?

Comment: @Rcordoval I have, but the output is still duplicated. The more i try to solve the problem, the more i'm thinking its something i'm doing with jaxb. Sadly i don't know for sure.

Comment: @Downvoter Reason for downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` to `@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)` in `Employees` class.

Alternatively move `@XmlElement(name = "Employee")` to `private List<Employee> employee;`.

The problem is, JAXB considers both `@XmlAccessorType` as well as explicit annotations. So it basically things you have two properties `employee` and `employees`, both mapped onto `Employee` element. This results in duplicate output.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your help! @lexicore